# Use array prototype methods recursively

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-class

I'm using an infinite-level structure, similar to this:

```
    {
  "name": "Group1",
  "type": "group",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "name": "Node1",
      "type": "node",
      "someproperty": "somevalue1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Group2",
      "type": "group",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "name": "Node2",
          "type": "node",
          "someproperty": "somevalue2"
        },
        {
          "name": "Node3",
          "type": "node",
          "someproperty": "somevalue3"
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Where we can have nodes inside groups, but also groups inside groups.

So far I've been writing recursive functions every time I need to do something, but the code is becoming quite unweildly.

I wondered if there was a way to create versions of Array.prototype methods but customise them to use recursion

e.g.to find any object (node or group) by id, I have a method

```
findNode(target, thisGroup) {

    if (typeof thisGroup == "undefined") {
        thisGroup = this;
    }

    // Am I the element?
    if (thisGroup.id == target) {
        return thisGroup;
    }

    // Look for element in my nodes
    var elementIx = thisGroup.nodes.findIndex(e => e.id == target);
    if (elementIx > 0) {
        // Found the element - return it
        return thisGroup.nodes[elementIx];
    }

    // Not found. Do I contain a group?
    var elementIx = thisGroup.nodes.findIndex(e => e.type == "group");

        if (elementIx > 0) {
            var nestGroup = thisGroup.nodes[elementIx];
            // If so, nest into this group and look again
            return this.findValue(target, nestGroup)
        }

    }
```

In the real world there's more than just `Id` I need to search/nest for. So how might I create my own prototype functions which I can then call like this?

```
thisGroup.nodes.findIndexRecursively(e => e.id == target)
thisGroup.nodes.findIndexRecursively(e => e.type=="node" && e.someProp == someValue)
```

Comment: what is the question about? to find (returning an object?) and/or to use a prototype of `Array`? where is `this` pointing to? maybe an instanciable or class is better for an object along with another for collections.

Comment: @NinaScholz   I'm looking for a tidy way of doing recursive logic - by default the array.prototype methods like "find" and "some" do not nest / are not recursive - so I'd like to create my own prototype methods. just not sure how!

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what you really want? Something like, with this data it should return this expected output. And also whether what you want is actually needed to be in "recursive" way?

Comment: If you want to put methods on `nodes`, you could just make a nodes `class` that extends `Array`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: "*So far I've been writing recursive functions every time I need to do something*" - there's no reason to stop that. Why do you think your code is becoming unweildly? Can you show us that code?

Comment: No, there's no good reason to make prototype methods in your data structures. `findIndexRecursively` should be a plain function. You should not need to modify or extend `Array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally wouldn't add this to the prototype, just a simple function should do.

Here is a simple example, it makes the assumption that it's all arrays you want to recursively traverse and check.

```js
const data = [{"name":"Group1","type":"group","nodes":[{"name":"Node1","type":"node","someproperty":"somevalue1"},{"name":"Group2","type":"group","nodes":[{"name":"Node2","type":"node","someproperty":"somevalue2"},{"name":"Node3","type":"node","someproperty":"somevalue3"}]}]}];


function rfind(arr, callback) {
  for (const a of arr) {
    const f = callback(a);
    if (f) return a;
    if (!f) {
      for (const o of Object.values(a)) {
        if (Array.isArray(o)) {
          const f2 = rfind(o, callback);
          if (f2) return f2;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


console.log(rfind(data, f => f.name==="Node1"));
console.log(rfind(data, f => f.name==="Node3"));
```

Comment: So is "callback" basically a means of passing in and using an arrow function?

Comment: Yes, in Javascript functions are basically objects, you can pass them around.  It's not just arrow functions either, normal functions can be passed too.

Comment: What if you wanted to return all matches, not just the first? I was considering prototype methods so I can use all the proto functions but recursively (e.g. filter, map)

Comment: You can build an array for your results to return all matches.  There are not that many Array methods, so re-implementing each one shouldn't be too hard.  Not sure there is a simple way that you could say, use `Array.filter`, but recursively, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive function and seach with a callback.

```js
function find(node, cb) {
    var result;
    if (cb(node)) return node;
    if (node.nodes) node.nodes.some(o => result = find(o, cb));
    return result;
}

var node = { name: "Group1", type: "group", nodes: [{ name: "Node1", type: "node", someproperty: "somevalue1" }, { name: "Group2", type: "group", nodes: [{ name: "Node2", type: "node", someproperty: "somevalue2" }, { name: "Node3", type: "node", someproperty: "somevalue3" }] }] },
    find1 = find(node, ({ type, someproperty }) => type === 'node' && someproperty === 'somevalue2'),
    find2 = find(node, ({ name, type }) => name === 'Group2' && type === 'group');

console.log(find1);
console.log(find2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```